# Using vim to efficiently reformat an associative array

Tags: php, vim

I need help figuring out a strategy for this problem. I find that I'm often collapsing a multi-line array down into one line, or expanding a one-liner into multiple lines.

Example:

```
$ary = ["this"=>"is an", "associative"=>"array"];
```

becomes

```
$ary = [
    "this" => "is an",
    "associative" => "array",
];
```

and vice versa. Notice in the multi-line version the trailing comma and the spaces around `=>`.

I'm not necessarily asking for a working answer, just some tips on how you would approach the problem. Would you start with a substitution? macro (recursive?)? vimscript function?

Comment: Actually the trailing `,` is now allowed in PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not sure what point you're making. I know trailing commas are allowed. I was pointing out that in the one-liner there is not a trailing comma but in the multi-liner there is. That's just a style choice my team uses and it's something that I add/remove manually when reformatting.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I missunderstod the question

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what makes you think vim is the wrong tool for the job? Can vim not do the job? Does vim take too long to do the job? Is it morally and inherently wrong? Or is it just wrong because that's just how it is and we should accept that?

Alternatively, vim could perhaps be one of the many solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect case for a substitution across select lines. The reason I think so is because

- you have clear definitions of what needs to be changed
- you know what you want it to be after you change it
- you know exactly which lines this change should apply to

Below is an example of a part of the solution (since you don't want full answers but rather the method)

**What needs to be changed**: comma + space
**What you want to replace it with**: comma + newline
**Which lines you want this to apply to**: ones you manually select

Visually select the lines, and press `:` to see

```
:'<,'>
```

which is a range selection representing your visual selection. Add to that until it looks like this:

```
:'<,'>s/, /,\r/g
```

which is saying "find and replace ALL comma+space with comma+newline on the lines I have visually selected".

now apply this logic to the other parts you want to change, such as turning
`"=>"` into `" => "`

However you might find the final answer to be a bit bulky, so you might want to map it to something if this is a frequent styling problem you encounter.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I've never done subs in visual mode. I just wanted to be aimed in the right direction, and your explanation gives me a good head start.